# Updating a database from multiple text boxes simultaneously when a specific userID is entered using C# - from an Admin user

Tags: c#, database, sql-update, multiple-columns

I am creating a personal information page for a project. This page will be able to submit and update personal information. I was looking to know how I can update my database when information is put into the text boxes. At the minute it will only update one field in the database at a time, if information is entered into one text box. It will not work if information is entered into multiple text boxes. I want to have it so that only the text boxes with text in them update the database, ie, if no information is entered into a text box it will not overwrite with a 'null' value. I am quite new to this so not quite sure how to do it.

When a specific userID is entered into the first text field the data relating to that specific userID should be updated. At the minute if I can enter text into any of the text boxes and it will update the table, but I need to be able to update multiple fields in the database at the same time when information is entered into multiple text boxes on the form. I think I have to do a loop but as I have very little programming experience with C# I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Please be aware this is from an admin user and security will be enhanced for other user sessions.

---

```
protected void Update_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        Label1.Text = "Updated";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QSTARConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();


        string updateifCmd = "UPDATE StaffPersonalInfo SET ";
        if (TextBox2.Text != "")
        {
            updateifCmd += "StaffPersonalTel = '" + TextBox2.Text + "' ";
        }


        if (TextBox3.Text != "")
        {
            updateifCmd += "StaffEmail = '" + TextBox3.Text + "' ";
        }


        if (TextBox4.Text != "")
        {
            updateifCmd += "StaffOfficeTel = '" + TextBox4.Text + "' ";
        }



        if (TextBox5.Text != "")
        {
            updateifCmd += "StaffEmergencyContact = '" + TextBox5.Text + "' ";
        }



        if (TextBox6.Text != "")
        {
            updateifCmd += "StaffBuilding = '" + TextBox6.Text + "' ";
        }



        if(TextBox7.Text != "")
        {
            updateifCmd += "StaffOfficeNum = '" + TextBox7.Text + "' ";

        }


        updateifCmd += "WHERE UserID='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand updateUser = new SqlCommand(updateifCmd, conn);



        try
        {
            updateUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Text = "Updated";
            conn.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Response.Write("Something went wrong.  Please try again");
        }

        finally
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Write("You have successfully updated the user");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I realise this is probably because you don't have much experience in programming but your code currently is very insecure and is open to attacks. Please look up SQL injections and how to prevent them in ASP.NET.

Comment: Yeah I realise this but it is only for a Uni project so it will not actually be live or accessible to anyone outside of my team apart from those marking it. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: @user3049791 The ones marking it might mark it down for security as it is, you might get bonus points if you do secure it. ;D  (PS; can you point out what part of it doesn't update when you press update? I can't really see the reason you can't update all listed boxes)

Comment: Haha Thanks Amber. This is from an admin side so more security will be added to the other user sessions. If I fill in one box and click update it will update that specific cell for the userID but if I enter  info into more than one text box it comes up with the error message. 'Something went wrong. Please try again. You have successfully updated the user' I was testing the arrangement of the code and commented out the 'IsPostBack' and inserting the 'successful update' into 'try', but just getting the error 'something went wrong'. I thought maybe a loop would work but not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Details View to update the information?

http://www.learn-asp.net/asptutorials/detailsview.aspx

You can just write your select, insert, delete and update statements in the data source(or have them generated for you if its not a complex query)